# Load file from remote location using jquery, ajax, google charts

Tags: ajax, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to load/read a csv file from my website without success. I have successfully managed to red the file locally but not from a url. Can somebody help me out?

Hereis my code that I have used:

```
var thecsvfile = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.aldindelic.se/test/data/data2.csv",
            dataType: "text/csv",
}
```

The whole code is at:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldin/zNkZL)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at the code you might also want to move the processing of the csv data to the success function of the ajax call. Remember it's async.

Answer (score 1):

Close function.It may help

```
var thecsvfile = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.aldindelic.se/test/data/data2.csv",
        dataType: "text/csv",
}***);***
```

After that,you will get error:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In short:  you need [enable](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (enable the necessary headers) on the server.